# Что тут происходит Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet()?

Tags: java, интерфейс, java-hashmap

Не понимаю работу `Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet()`. Как мы можем создать `Map.Entry<K, V>`, если это интерфейс? Мы же не можем создавать интерфейсы. Можно подробнее объяснить и показать применяется ли это где-то еще?

Comment: в HashMap класс называется Node,  static class Node<K, V> implements Entry<K, V> . почему мы создаем все таки Map.Entry<K, V> , а не HashMap().Node() как то так.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Суть полиморфизма состоит в том, что за некоторым интерфейсом, можно скрыть детали реализации.

Например мы хотим создать стек, его упрощённый интерфейс будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
public interface Stack<T>{
    public void add(T t);
    public T pop();
}
```

Какие реализации можно предложить? На самом деле их множество, можно использовать `ArrayList`, можно использовать массив, если мы, допустим, знаем максимальный размер. Возможно вы захотите использовать `LinkedList`. Однако задайте вопрос, при использовании стека вам нужно знать какая именно реализация скрывается за этим интерфейсом? Скорее всего нет, вы просто знаете, что есть методы `add` и `pop`, а как элементы расположатся в памяти, вас не волнует. Вы просто используете стек.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Stack<Integer> stack = new MyStackLinkedList();
  processing(stack);
  Stack<Integer> stack2 = new MyStackArrayList();
  processing(stack);
}

//метод не знает, какая именно реализация используется, но ему достаточно знать об add и pop
public static void processing(Stack<Integer> stack) { 
   stack.add(1);
   stack.add(15);
   stack.pop();
}
```

Также и в случае `Map.Entry<K, V>`, конкретная реализация скрыта, вдруг мы поймём как оптимизировать `HashMap` в будущем, для обратной совместимости всех продуктов, нам будет достаточно изменить или написать новую реализацию `Node`, но весь остальной код, менять не придётся.

Comment: var test = new HashMap<String,String>(); Map.Entry<String,String> ptr = (Map.Entry<String, String>) test; Так не будет работать( примерно понял, но где то что то не понимаю.

Comment: hashmap не реализует интерфейс Map.Entry, Node реализует.

Answer (score 1):

EntrySet - это значения Map (тоесть ключ-значение). Каждая пара ключ-значение представляет собой Entry.
Что вообще такое map - это ассоциативный массив, в котором (конкретно в реализации HashMap) по хешу ключа ищется значение. Если возникла коллизия и хеш коды ключей совпадают, значения по этому хешу складываются в односвязный список (до 8 элементов, потом превращается в красно черное дерево, но при норм определении хеш функции такое не происходит, плюс loadfactor частично предотвращает такие ситуэйшн, кароче мелочей много и мы их пока опустим)
Но как мы видим, Set и Map это  разные коллекции, но не концептуально. Дело в том, что Set под капотом использует Map - наш ассоциативный массив, только в качестве значений он оставляет null. Поэтому, если мы говорим о реализации HashSet в java и почему эта структура данных работает за постоянное O(1) время (при извлечении ключа), то это тот же ассоциативный масчив - Entry, просто ключ - уникальное K, а V - null, и когда мы просим отдать нам такой-то элемент, он заранее знает, на каком индексе он лежит (он вызывает функцию hashCode() класса Object и по модулю деления на длину этого массива определяет на какой ячейке он лежит - тоесть, допустим, hashCode вернул 31, а начальная емность HashSet у нас 16 - > значит мы делаем 31%16=15(остаток от деления). В 15 ячейке нашего массива и лежит наш элемент. И, когда мы его достаем, мы его не ищем, а тупо к нему обращаемся, отсюда и скорость работы)

Но если подвести итоги - то Set просто под капотом юзает Map (обратите внимание, map не реализует iterable, в отличие от set, но getValues() и getKeys() методы мапы реализуют)